# how to enable scrolling for background image position fixed

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, css-position

I have container-fluid to which i need to give full page width background . I have achieved this by giving position fixed and height 100%. But the real problem now is I am getting scroll when the content is more height than the browser height. Kindly help to achieve it. My project is built under **bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="container-fluid kyc-page" >
    <h1 class="head-text">KYC Verification</h1>
    <div class="bannerWrapper"></div></div>
```

css:

```
.container-fluid.kyc-page {
    background-image: url(../images/banner-img2.png);
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Kindly help to achieve the content over flow and full background image

Comment: Can you try to add `overflow:auto;` to the div, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid kyc-page" >
<h1 class="head-text">KYC Verification</h1>
<div class="bannerWrapper">
```

CSS:

```
.container-fluid.kyc-page {
background-image: url('img.jpg');
height: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

}

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please

Comment: You just replace position: fixed;  with  background-attachment: fixed; Through this in case of scrolling your background image fixed but content scroll. Ok